# Remove Certain Characters in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table value

```
Berdasarkan waktu <span id="c__0_3228" class="ctext" title="Klik untuk mengedit kata">**penyelenggaraan**</span> pameran bisa dibedakan menjadi 3 jenis, berikut adalah jenis jenis pameran berdasarkan waktu. Simak dengan baik!
```

And

- I want to delete `<span> to </span>`
- Just wanted to be left  **penyelenggaraan**

After Result:
Berdasarkan waktu **penyelenggaraan** pameran bisa dibedakan menjadi 3 jenis, berikut adalah jenis jenis pameran berdasarkan waktu. Simak dengan baik!

--
Here the id, class or title values are all different.

The query also applies to

```
<span id="example123">**EXAMPLE123**</span>
```

Comment: doing this in MySQL instead of for example PHP will be terribly slow

Comment: I'm totally lost.  The first take is `<span` not `<span>` and yet you say you want to remove it.  "penyelenggaraan" is between the tags.  The rules you specify and the results you want are inconsistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do you what you need.

`SET` is just to set a variable so we can work with it. You can just use the field itself.

The [POSITION()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_position.asp) function returns the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string.

In this case, `POSITION()` finds the positions of `>**` and `**<` within the `@fieldval` variable to extract the data. `+ 3` and `- 3` are to account for the extra characters from what we are looking for in `POSITION()`.

[MID()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_mid.asp) extracts everything between the two `POSITION()`.

```
SET @fieldval = "Berdasarkan waktu <span id=c__0_3228 class=ctext title=Klik untuk mengedit kata>**penyelenggaraan**</span> pameran bisa dibedakan menjadi 3 jenis, berikut adalah jenis jenis pameran berdasarkan waktu. Simak dengan baik!";

SELECT MID(@fieldval, POSITION(">**" IN @fieldval) + 3, POSITION("**<" IN @fieldval) - POSITION(">**" IN @fieldval) - 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first get the beginning and ending indices of the string you want to remove. You can use the following SELECT statement to get the indicies:

```
SELECT CHARINDEX("<span", col_name, 0) as start_ind, CHARINDEX("</span>", col_name, 0) as end_ind FROM table_name
```

Keep in mind that the statement above will give you the index of the first instance of "<span." If you want to get all instances, you may want to repeat the procedure every time after you update the string, removing one "span" block after another until there are no more blocks
Then you can update the value of the field as follows:

```
UPDATE table_name set col_name = SUBSTRING(col_name, 0, start_ind) + SUBSTRING(col_name, end_index + 1, LEN(col_name) - end_ind) WHERE <condition>
```

Comment: I think this answer is for MSSQL, whereas the question is tagged with `MySQL`..